# how to place text left/right in html?

Tags: html

Is it possible to place text in html left and right

I want it to place the text left and right on the same line.

My HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>RPG Clicker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
       <left>Level: <span id="level">1</span></left>
       <right>Gon level: <span id="gon">0</span></right>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5q3rkmxg/)

Comment: are you familiar with CSS floats?

Comment: I don't think any `<left>` or `<right>` tag exist in `HTML` or `HTML5`, you can align them inline using `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<left>` or `<right>` tag in html. 
To achieve what you want to do, you will have to do it with CSS.

```css
.align-left {
  float: left;
  width:33%;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width:34%;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="align-left">Level: <span id="level">1</span></span>
    <span class="align-center">Text</span>
    <span class="align-right">Gon level: <span id="gon">0</span></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="textbox">
  <p class="alignleft">Text on the left.</p>
  <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
```

SOURCE:[Left Align and Right Align Text on the Same Line](https://css-tricks.com/left-align-and-right-align-text-on-the-same-line/)

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
<span style="float:right">Right</span>
<span style="float:left">Left</span>
```

Comment: What about "Center"? Because I tryed to do "float:center" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

- a table with one row and two columns, the left one left-aligned, the right one right-aligned;
- a CSS grid system with a "row" and two "columns": right-align the second column (see eg. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid);
- a div with `float: right; text-align: right;` that you place *before* your left-aligned content.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
<left style="float:left">Level: <span id="level">1</span></left>
<center style="
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 45%;
">Text</center>
    <right style="float:right">Gon level: <span id="gon">0</span></right>
```

you can get more info about floats and position from w3schools.com